# Combining two launch.json configurations to run sequentially in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

As part of a .NET Core 2.0 project I'm starting up a .dll then launching Chrome to debug the front end via the Debugger for Chrome extension.

If I launch both manually as such:

```
{
        "name": "[Development] Launch Server",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/Website.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "LocalDevelopment"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
        }
    }
```

and then

```
{
        "name": "[Development] Debug Browser",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:5000/home",
        "port": 9222,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:///./*": "${workspaceRoot}\\*"
        }
    }
```

everything works great. However, this is a slow process because the 'Launch Server' configuration takes a few minutes to build/release and then I must manually launch 'Debug Browser'.

Ideally I would have a 'one click' solution that handles the first configuration and upon release starts up the second configuration.

I have tried:

```
"compounds": [
    {
        "name": "[Development] Launch Server & Debug Browser",
        "configurations": [
            "[Development] Launch Server",
            "[Development] Debug Browser"
        ]
    }
]
```

but this just ends up launching the first configuration and receiving this error[image]

while the second configuration seemingly never firing off. I've looked into tasks.json but I'm not sure that's the right place for what I'm trying to accomplish.

How can I turn this into a fire and forget?